# How to right or left shift a block of text by a specific number of columns?

Tags: vim

If I use `vim`,
put the cursor on the beginning of a line, and then input

```
    3>> or 3<<
```

I can left or right shift 3 lines by 8 columns

If I just want to shift 4 columns, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set shiftwidth=4
```

and then use **3>>** as normal

Comment: Source: http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html